# Can't get ACF fields after creating a new page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

We are developing a crowd-funding platform based on Wordpress' "advanced custom fields". In order to create a new funding-project we fill ACF-fields (in a HTML-form). On submitting we create a new WP-page:

```
$post = array(
        'post_name'      => $pname,
        'post_title'     => $pname,
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'post_parent'    => 8,
        'page_template'  => 'project.php'
    );

$this->post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
```

Strangely we cannot access the field variables with `get_field(" ... ")` before we manually click onto "Save" or "Publish" on the page in the Wordpress backend.
`wp_update_post()` or `wp_publish_post()` make no difference.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand, you want the value of the fields before you click "save" or "publish"? what are you trying to do

Comment: we save a new page as draft and add several custom field entries to it (all done via php). when we then want to access those ACF-fields they are empty. when we go to the backend and choose our created page, the fields are visible. ONLY when we click onto "Save" in the backend, we can access the fields via PHP get_field()

Answer (score 0):

We just found the solution!
Using the field key instead of the field name on filling the fields worked!